# How do I monitor the status of a Geth sync in fast mode?

Tags: go-ethereum

I started up a fresh Geth node and it's syncing in fast mode. I'm currently here:

```
INFO [10-26|18:11:04.053] Imported new state entries               count=768  elapsed=63.553ms    processed=245780433 pending=100559 trieretry=0   coderetry=0 duplicate=247 unexpected=903
```

How do I know how far along it is in its sync? It says I've currently processed 245780433 trie nodes; is the total number of nodes known? Alternately, is the disk usage of a fast sync known?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Input this command (vary the datadir to reflect your system if necessary, and you can issue this command remotely with the IP and port number of your geth machine)

```
sudo geth attach --datadir /var/lib/goethereum/
```

then at the > prompt type eth.syncing

You'll see something like the output below -- it's a two stage process, in the first, the distance between the "CurrentBlock" and the "HighestBlock" will decrease until they are almost equal. It will then look stuck and like it's never catching up. But you should see "PulledStates" rising to meet "KnownStates." When both numbers catch up, your synced.

```
{
  currentBlock: 11767544,
  highestBlock: 11790961,
  knownStates: 628485238,
  pulledStates: 628485238,
  startingBlock: 11790248
}
```

A response of "false", unintuitively, means you're all good and synced up.